# How to extract all datas from xml DOM in node JS

Tags: node.js, express

I am going to extract all attributes and texts from xml DOM in express
Now I am using xml-query node module

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <OrderMessageBatch batchNumber="3012566157">
    <hubOrder transactionID="3001372018">
      <lineItem>
        <lineItemId>3001389044</lineItemId>
        <orderLineNumber>1</orderLineNumber>
        <merchantLineNumber>1</merchantLineNumber>
        <qtyOrdered>3</qtyOrdered>
        <unitOfMeasure>EA</unitOfMeasure>
        <UPC>9999999990101</UPC>
        <poLineData />
      </lineItem>
      <personPlace personPlaceID="PP3012385024">
        <name1>John Doe</name1>
        <address1>1 Fuller Road</address1>
        <city>Albany</city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <postalCode>12203</postalCode>
        <dayPhone>555-555-5555</dayPhone>
      </personPlace>
      <personPlace personPlaceID="PP3012385026">
        <name1>Mary Smith</name1>
        <address1>123 THD Lane</address1>
        <city>Atlanta</city>
        <state>GA</state>
        <postalCode>30339</postalCode>
        <email>sample@email.com</email>
        <partnerPersonPlaceId>8119</partnerPersonPlaceId>
      </personPlace>
      <personPlace personPlaceID="PP3012385025">
        <name1>Home Depot</name1>
        <partnerPersonPlaceId>8119</partnerPersonPlaceId>
      </personPlace>
    </hubOrder>
<hubOrder transactionID="3001372018">
      <lineItem>
        <lineItemId>3001389044</lineItemId>
        <orderLineNumber>1</orderLineNumber>
        <merchantLineNumber>1</merchantLineNumber>
        <qtyOrdered>3</qtyOrdered>
        <unitOfMeasure>EA</unitOfMeasure>
        <UPC>9999999990101</UPC>
        <poLineData />
      </lineItem>
      <personPlace personPlaceID="PP3012385024">
        <name1>John Doe</name1>
        <address1>1 Fuller Road</address1>
        <city>Albany</city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <postalCode>12203</postalCode>
        <dayPhone>555-555-5555</dayPhone>
      </personPlace>
      <personPlace personPlaceID="PP3012385026">
        <name1>Mary Smith</name1>
        <address1>123 THD Lane</address1>
        <city>Atlanta</city>
        <state>GA</state>
        <postalCode>30339</postalCode>
        <email>sample@email.com</email>
        <partnerPersonPlaceId>8119</partnerPersonPlaceId>
      </personPlace>
      <personPlace personPlaceID="PP3012385025">
        <name1>Home Depot</name1>
        <partnerPersonPlaceId>8119</partnerPersonPlaceId>
      </personPlace>
    </hubOrder>
```

As you can see there are several hubOrder attributes in xml file and and each hubOrder attribute have many personPlace attributes.
Now xmlDOM.find('orderLineNumber').text() lists texts not regarding to xml structrure
Is there any node module to extract all neccessary datas?
Or what can I do on with this module?

Comment: What is `orderId`? It does not appear in the XML document.

Comment: I have edited content

Comment: Yours is not a valid XML document, because it has more than one top-level node (`hubOrder`). Valid XML has only one top-level node (e.g., `hubOrders`).

Comment: fixed so now valid xml

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.map`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-query#map) function to convert the result of `.find` to an array, for example:

```
xmlQuery(xmlDOM).find("hubOrder").map(
  hubOrder => xmlQuery(hubOrder).find("lineItem").map(
    lineItem => xmlQuery(lineItem).find("orderLineNumber").text()
  )
)
```